# Trying to determine managedby attribute for specific distributionlist

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I've a text file with a list of distribution groups that I'm trying to get managedby attribute. I tried running different commands but seems to be a syntax issue ( fairly new to PowerShell) because I'm able to retrieve the attribute managedby for single distribution group. When I'm formatting and exporting the result to csv file all I get is a bunch of numbers. I'm on powershell exchange server 2008.

Comment: An example of your text file and your code would be helpful

Comment: Exchange version could be useful on top of that. Your code example would be more important as we can try and correct the issue.

Comment: With an example of what code you're trying, it wouldn't be too much trouble to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a flat text file named groups.txt:

```
Employees@company.com
Executives@company.com
```

### Suggested Solution:

```
$grouplist = Get-Content groups.txt | foreach {Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $_ | Select-Object PrimarySMTPaddress, ManagedBy}
$grouplist | Export-Csv -Path results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Gives results like:

```
"PrimarySmtpAddress","ManagedBy"
"Employees@company.com","admin"
"Executives@company.com","admin"
```

### Reproducing the "bunch of numbers" issue:

```
$grouplist = Get-Content groups.txt | foreach {Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $_ | Select-Object PrimarySMTPaddress, ManagedBy}
Export-Csv -InputObject $grouplist -Path results2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Resulted in:

```
"Count","Length","LongLength","Rank","SyncRoot","IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized"
"2","2","2","1","System.Object[]","False","True","False"
```

---

Environment: Exchange 2013, Powershell 5.0, Windows 10 Tech Preview 3

Comment: I tried the same exact thing the only difference is I had no -notypeinformation. The command some how Is not able to retrieve the content from the text file. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Rahul If your command isn't able to retrieve the contents of the text file, you probably need the full path i.e. `C\Users\Currentusername\Desktop\groups.txt` I usually make my working directory the same as the folder I placed the file.